# redirecting to a different directory using htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I'm trying to redirect the following

/books/categories/mountain-literature/my-father-frank.html

to

/books/categories/baton-wicks/my-father-frank.html

This is the line in my .htaccess

```
RedirectMatch 301 /mountain-literature(.*) /books/categories/baton-wicks$1
```

it rewrites the url and appends this pageUrl stuff on which I don't want and the correct page doesn't load ?

books/categories/baton-wicks/my-father-frank.html?pageUrl=books/categories/mountain-literature/my-father-frank&contentType=html

Answer (score 0):

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^mountain-literature/(.*)$ /baton-wicks/$1 [L,R=301]
```

try this or this

```
Redirect 301 /mountain-literature /baton-wicks
```

Answer (score 0):

If you dont need the rewrite rule to match multiple URL's, try just hardcoding the `target` URL, i.e.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule mountain-literature/(.*) /books/categories/baton-wicks/my-father-frank.html [L,R=301]
```

By adding the `[L]` flag it should tell apache not to allow any other rules to append to the URI

Comment: same problem, it rewrites the url but appends ?pageUrl=books/categories/mountain-literature/my-father-frank&contentType=html to the end of it?

Comment: updated my answer again, sorry, the `^` should not be at the front of the pattern.

Comment: nothing happens. Mainly redirectmatch is making something happen, but [L] after it causes a http 500 error